# Active Storage with Texteditor?

Tags: image, tinymce, blogs, shrine, trix

I am very new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails but I am trying to develop my own little Blog project. I followed a pretty good guide on YouTube to get started with it. Currently I can create posts, edit and delete them and they are getting pretty okay displayed with a bootstrap css. For new blog post I use tinymce, which could be a problem for what I want to do.

My aim is to implement a image gallery with images only and the ability to implement images in my posts. So when Iam writing a post that I can implement one or more images in that post. And these images should automatically be added in the image gallery.

Maybe it was a bit naive but I thought this have to be possible, but seem pretty hard. With active storage I can only attach files before or after my post and that’s not what I want to do. I read about trix and shrine, but trix isn’t really working for me, maybe my post model isn’t right therefore? Seems like it’s not rendering.

Is my idea even possible ? What do I have to do? I loved to build up my blog and fixing errors and stuff but now it seems I can’t get it to work.

Comment: I don't think there is any way for the people on stackoverflow.com to help you without sharing some code and the exact errors you are facing. what does "isn't really working for me" means? Without such information how can we help you?

Comment: Welcome to SO Sebastian. Unfortunately your question is not well suited to SO and is better suited to a forum or subreddit. SO is a Q&A format site for specific programming questions. I'm flagging to close this one.